# Why is my Jenkins step not retrying and instead throwing a timeout error when the time limit is not reached?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

In my Jenkins pipeline, I have the following Jenkins step constructed using Jenkins scripted syntax. Its purpose is to run a docker container, which runs some integration tests. I currently spawn 11 of these steps in parallel.

```
node('tester') {
    stage("Test") {
        withEnv([
            "USERNAME=some_user",
            "UID=1000",
            "GID=1000"
        ]) {
            dir("some_directory") {
                // ... some steps here
                retry(1) {
                    try {
                        timeout(time: 15, unit: 'MINUTES') {
                            retry(1) {
                                sh "docker-compose --project-name tester_prod9 -f docker-compose.e2e.yml -- up --build --renew-anon-volumes --exit-code-from cypress --timeout 600"
                            }
                        }
                    } catch (err) {
                        error "Timeout!"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, I want my `docker-compose` command to retry once if the `docker-compose` command fails. However, if this process (including a potential retry) exceeds 15 minutes, I want a timeout error to be thrown. If a timeout error is thrown, I would all of this to be retried once more.

However, the above desired steps are not happening.

Currently, when my `docker-compose` command fails on the first run, a "Timeout!" error is thrown and the whole step ends.

As you can see below, the `docker-compose` command only runs for 8 minutes so a timeout error shouldn't be thrown. Also, the `docker-compose` command is never retried by Jenkins.

[image]

**How can I fix my Jenkins step in order to achieve my desired behaviour?**

My Jenkins version is 2.270.

**Edit:**

Just to be clear, I expect the `docker-compose` command to fail because there is a failing test inside the Docker container. However, Jenkins isn't retrying the failed `docker-compose` command as expected.

Comment: Did you check from the Jenkins logs that you are not running out of memory or something else going on?

Comment: Just took a look and there definitely isn't an out of memory issue and I can't see any other glaring problems. Just to clarify, the `docker-compose` command is legitimately failing because of a failed integration test. So failing is the correct behaviour. Unfortunately, Jenkins isn't retrying that failed command as expected.

Comment: Could you try to set higher number of retries, e.g. 2 or 3 and see if that changes behaviour?

Comment: @ymochurad Trying that right now. Hoping it works...

Comment: @ymochurad it worked! Setting a retry value of 2 actually got it to retry! I can't explain why and I'm not sure if this is a bug but the inner-most retry section works for me now when the `docker-compose` command fails...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not found anywhere any information about `retry` should be > 1. Official [documentation](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-basic-steps/#retry-retry-the-body-up-to-n-times) says:

```
retry: Retry the body up to N times
Retry the block (up to N times) if any exception happens during its body execution. 
If an exception happens on the final attempt then it will lead to aborting the build 
(unless it is caught and processed somehow). User aborts of the build are not caught.
```

But it looks that in order to trigger retries it should be set to more than 1

Answer (score 0):

Although the official documentation suggests that retry(n) will `Retry the body up to N times`, in reality n is the total number of attempts, so for one retry you will need to set retry(2).
Trust me, I discovered this the hard way!